# MFi-compliant accessory drops bluetooth connection to iPhone after about 1kb of data

Tags: ios, bluetooth, external-accessory, mfi

I'm having a hard time tracking down an issue with an accessory I'm developing. It plays nice by the MFi rules - I can pair with it, connect to it and get some data. The problem is that it either disconnects on its own, or gets hung up on by the iPhone.

Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?